# transfer of control bypasses initialization of:

Tags: c++

Basically, I'm trying to use OPENFILENAME to open a txt file, but it outputs the directory of the file. I want it to output the content of the txt file.

I'm having an issue with my code; here it is:

```
OPENFILENAME ofn;
char szFile[100];

ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
ofn.hwndOwner = NULL;
ofn.lpstrFile = szFile;
ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
ofn.nMaxFile = sizeof(szFile);
ofn.lpstrFilter = "All\0*.*\0Text\0*.TXT\0";
ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
ofn.nMaxFileTitle = 0;
ofn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;
ofn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;

GetOpenFileName(&ofn);

std::string line = " ";

fstream infile;
infile.open(ofn.lpstrFile);

Print(ofn.lpstrFile);
```

That creates an error:
[image: error]

All help will be appreciated, thank you. The

```
std::string line = " ";

fstream infile;
infile.open(ofn.lpstrFile);

Print(ofn.lpstrFile);
```

is the problem.

edit:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK DLLWindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (wParam)
        {
        case MYMENU_OPENSCRIPT:
            OPENFILENAME ofn;
            char szFile[100];

            ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
            ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
            ofn.hwndOwner = NULL;
            ofn.lpstrFile = szFile;
            ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
            ofn.nMaxFile = sizeof(szFile);
            ofn.lpstrFilter = "All\0*.*\0Text\0*.TXT\0";
            ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
            ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
            ofn.nMaxFileTitle = 0;
            ofn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;
            ofn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;

            GetOpenFileName(&ofn);

            std::string line = " ";

            fstream infile;
            infile.open(ofn.lpstrFile);

            Print(ofn.lpstrFile);

            break;
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to have local variables inside one of the cases of a `switch` statement, you need to create a new block.

In the below, `y` is still in scope after the `case 1` label, so when `x` is 1, the initialization of `y` will be bypassed. This is not allowed; in C++, a variable that is in scope is supposed to have been initialized.

```
switch (x) {
  case 0:
    int y = 42;
    // ...
  case 1:
    // ...
}
```

To fix this, add extra braces so that `case 0` has its own scope, and `y` is not visible in `case 1`.

```
switch (x) {
  case 0: {
    int y = 42;
    // ...
  }
  case 1: {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I've attempted to use that, is this right? Or am I just not thinking right or being dumb.

http://pastebin.com/raw/A76zLpgG

Comment: @OmneyPixel I don't see the extra braces.

Comment: I forgot about them; but i've added them now. Thanks for the help, I fixed it with that :D

Comment: edit: It didn't error; although it didn't print anything. I've tried messageboxes, but it always prints " ". No clue what's happening, tried with c_str() and without. Nothing. Any help?

Comment: @OmneyPixel I think you should post a new question.